# How to update a period automatically according to date?

Tags: c#, .net

I created a response class, where it converts int to data. In StartPeriod you choose the day that period will start and in PostingPeriod the number of days in that period.  This calculation is processed, PostingStartDate and PostingPeriodDate is not written to the database

```
namespace Period
{
    public class PeriodResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int StartPeriod { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PostingPeriod { get; set; }


        public DateTime StartPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertStartPeriod(PostingStart); }
        }

        public DateTime EndPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertPostingPeriod(PostingStart, PostingPeriod); }
        }


        private DateTime ConvertStartPeriod (int startPeriod)
        {
            return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, startPeriod);
        }

        private DateTime ConvertPostingPeriod (int startPeriod, int postingPeriod)
        {
            var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
            var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);

            var periodEndDay = startPeriod + postingPeriod - 1;

            if (periodEndDay > daysInMonth)
            {
                periodEndDay = periodEndDay - daysInMonth + 1;
                currentMonth++;

                if (currentMonth > 12)
                {
                    currentMonth = 1;
                    currentYear++;
                }
            }

            return new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, periodEndDay);
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a catch. For example, having the Period Start starting on the 20th and the number of days as 20 as well, the answer would look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "startPeriodDate": "2023-04-20",
    "endPeriodDate": "2023-05-10"
}
```

The problem is that when turning the month, for example, if we are on May 1st, this value is recalculated. I didn't want this to happen, I would like the value to only be recalculated again after the current date is greater than the endPeriodDate date. In theory, this value would only be updated after May 11

I've tried everything and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DateTime.AddDays()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-7.0) instead of trying to calculate it by yourself.

It returns an object whose value is the sum of the date and time represented by this instance and the number of days represented by value which is much easier.

Here is how can you use it for your case:

```cs
        public DateTime StartPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertStartPeriod(StartPeriod); }
        }

        public DateTime EndPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertPostingPeriod(StartPeriodDate, PostingPeriod); }
        }


        private DateTime ConvertStartPeriod(int startPeriod)
        {
            return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, startPeriod);
        }

        private DateTime ConvertPostingPeriod(DateTime date, int period)
        {
            return date.AddDays(period);
        }
```

Comment: Got it... But will it work automatically? I have this doubt

Comment: @AntônioRocha What do you mean about automatically? If I got the question right, it will calculate automatically based on the days of the months. Here is the microsoft documentation about the method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Types of methods and ways to add(Year,month,day) in date

use AddMonths to add the specified number of months to the value of this instance.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);   // (yyyy,MM,dd)
date = date.AddMonths(14);
```

use AddYears to add the specified number of Years to the value of this instance.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);   // (yyyy,MM,dd)
date = date.AddYears(14);
```

use addDay and TimeSpan to add the specified number of Days to the value of this instance.

1.with AddDays

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);   // (yyyy,MM,dd)
date = date.AddDays(1);
```

2.Using TimeSpan to add days

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);   // (yyyy,MM,dd)
TimeSpan offset = new(days: 1, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0, milliseconds: 0);
date = date.Add(offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you didn't not save which month and year into the database

```
namespace Period
{
    public class PeriodResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int StartPeriod { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PostingPeriod { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int StartPeriodMonth { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Month;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int StartPeriodYear { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Year;

        public DateTime StartPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertStartPeriod(PostingStart); }
        }

        public DateTime EndPeriodDate
        {
            get { return ConvertPostingPeriod(PostingStart, PostingPeriod); }
        }


        private DateTime ConvertStartPeriod (int startPeriod)
        {
            return new DateTime(StartPeriodYear, StartPeriodMonth, startPeriod);
        }

        private DateTime ConvertPostingPeriod (int startPeriod, int postingPeriod)
        {
            
            return new DateTime(StartPeriodYear, StartPeriodMonth, startPeriod).AddDays(postingPeriod);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace Period
{
public class PeriodResponse
{
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int StartPeriod { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int PostingPeriod { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartPeriodDate
    {
        get { return ConvertStartPeriod(StartPeriod); }
    }

    public DateTime GetEndPeriodDate()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > EndPeriodDate)
        {
            return ConvertPostingPeriod(StartPeriod, PostingPeriod);
        }
        else
        {
            return EndPeriodDate;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _endPeriodDate;

    private DateTime EndPeriodDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_endPeriodDate == default(DateTime))
            {
                _endPeriodDate = ConvertPostingPeriod(StartPeriod, PostingPeriod);
            }
            return _endPeriodDate;
        }
    }

    private DateTime ConvertStartPeriod(int startPeriod)
    {
        return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, startPeriod);
    }

    private DateTime ConvertPostingPeriod(int startPeriod, int postingPeriod)
    {
        var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);

        var periodEndDay = startPeriod + postingPeriod - 1;

        if (periodEndDay > daysInMonth)
        {
            periodEndDay = periodEndDay - daysInMonth + 1;
            currentMonth++;

            if (currentMonth > 12)
            {
                currentMonth = 1;
                currentYear++;
            }
        }

        return new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, periodEndDay);
    }
}
```

}